# Using an already-defined struct as an anonymous member of a union

Tags: c++, c++17, anonymous-class

Let's say I have a 32-bit hardware register `Reg` that I want to be able to access either as a 32-bit value (e.g. `Reg = 0x12345678`) or as bitfields (e.g. `Reg.lsw = 0xABCD`). I can achieve this by declaring a union with anonymous struct member, and declaring assignment and conversion operators to/from `uint32_t`. In a little-endian environment, the code might look like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

typedef union
  {
  uint32_t val ;
  struct
    {
    uint32_t lsw : 16 ;
    uint32_t msw : 16 ;
    } ;

  operator = (uint32_t n) { val = n ; }
  operator uint32_t() const { return val ; }
  } HWR ;

int main()
  {
  HWR Reg ;
  Reg = 0x12345678 ;
  Reg.lsw = 0xABCD ;
  printf ("%X\n", uint32_t(Reg)) ;
  }
```

But now let's say I have a whole bunch of these registers, each with its own bitfield layout, and I have a header file `FieldDefs.h` that declares these bitfield layouts as named structures. How can I use these named structures in the above code, so that I can access the 32-bit value and also the individual bitfields? I could do it like this:

```
#include "FieldDefs.h" // Defines struct MyHWR
typedef union
  {
  uint32_t val ;
  struct MyHWR field ;

  operator = (uint32_t n) { val = n ; }
  operator uint32_t() const { return val ; }
  } MyHWRUnion ;
```

But now instead of `Reg.lsw =...`, I need to type `Reg.field.lsw =...`

Is there any way (in C++17) to declare an already defined struct as an anonymous member of a union? I am using g++ version 7.3.0 if it matters.

Comment: As I am looking again at the problem definition and my answer I have a feeling that I overcomplicated it a little.. Is access by `Reg.val` part of the interface?

Comment: @R2RT: Good question! In my code snippet, it doesn't have to be; but I also find myself wanting to do things like `Reg.val &= 0xFF`, which do require `val` to be accessible. I could write `Reg = uint32_t(Reg) & 0xFF`, I suppose.

Comment: Ok, then my code can be even simplified to work in older g++s without `val` exposed. Gonna add it to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose none will like this answer, neither OP (since requires `g++ 9.1`), neither C++ gurus (UB smells?), but I am still a little proud of tinkering it.

There is [`[[no_unique_address]]` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) coming in C++20 and g++ 9.1 already supports it (even without `-std=c++2a` flag).

How can it be utilized here?
[By test and trials](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fdBkcE) it seems that if we create proxy member `val` marked with it it will take address of object<sup>1</sup>.

Thus we can create `Proxy` class which has `operator=(uint32_t)` and `operator uint32_t` that treats `this` as `uint32_t`. The proxy object has no address, does not increase size of struct that utilizes it.

Bitfields names have to be added by inheritance, which got wrapped in simple template, for consistency named `HWR`.

Voilà, we have `HWR<bitfield>` object which can be assigned to `uint32_t` directly, by `val` member and gives access to bitfields names.

https://godbolt.org/z/N2xEmz

```
#include <bits/stdint-uintn.h>

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

// Example bifields, I assumed you have such in "FieldDefs.h"
struct bitfield {
  uint32_t lsw : 16;
  uint32_t msw : 16;
};

struct ThisProxy {
  uint32_t& operator=(uint32_t n) {
    auto& uint = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(this);
    uint = n;
    return uint;
  }
  operator uint32_t() const { return *reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(this); }
};

template <typename Bitfield>
struct HWR : Bitfield {
  static_assert(sizeof(Bitfield) == 4, "Bad things would happen");
  HWR& operator=(uint32_t n) {
    this->val = n;
    return *this;
  }
  operator uint32_t() const { return this->val; }
  [[no_unique_address]] ThisProxy val;
};

int main() {
  HWR<bitfield> Reg;
  // Sanity check that proxy points at &Reg and does not increase size
  static_assert(offsetof(HWR<bitfield>, val) == 0, "");
  static_assert(sizeof(HWR<bitfield>) == 4, "");

  Reg = 0x12345678;
  Reg.val = 0x8765432A;
  Reg.lsw = 0xABCA;
  printf("%X\n%ld\n", uint32_t(Reg), sizeof(Reg));

  return 0;
}
```

Edit:

As it turned out that access by `Reg.val` is not mandatory the trick with inheritance + `reinterpret_cast` can be reused in pre-C++20 code.

```
template <typename Bitfield> struct HWR : Bitfield {
  static_assert(sizeof(Bitfield) == 4, "Bad things would happen");
  HWR &operator=(uint32_t n) {
    *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(this) = n;
    return *this;
  }
  operator uint32_t() const {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t *>(this);
  }
};
```

There is still smell of `reinterpret_cast` and I need to find out oine thing to fully recommend this code. Whenever bitfield can be interpreted by underlying type `uint32_t`.

<sup>1</sup> I am not sure whenever offset of 0 is guaranteed by [P0840R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0840r2.html).

<sup>PS. g++ complains with `warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘HWR<bitfield>’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]`, but I didn't try to find workaround for it.</sup>

<sup>PPS. No anonymous structs!</sup>

Comment: R2RT, you are a programmer after my own heart! I have implemented this solution in my code, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

```
union
{
// ...
    struct
    {
    // ...
    };
```

This is an anonymous struct. Anonymous structs are ill-formed in C++. Only unions may be anonyous. This is different from C where anonymous structs are allowed (since C11).

> Is there any way (in C++17) to declare an already defined struct as an anonymous member of a union?

No. Unnamed members cannot have a named type.

You'll need to make a choice between the unnamed member and the pre-declared class. Given that the anonymous struct is non-standard in the first place, I recommend going with the named member and pre-defined class. Maybe give it a short name to minimise verbosity.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about using ill-formed code, as long as it compiles and runs. After all, I am already in a machine-dependent environment, with hardware registers and all. But your last paragraph looks right to me -- what I want just can't be done.

Comment: @TonyK Just keep in mind that you aren't writing C++, but rather a compiler specific variant of C++, if you use compiler specific features.